# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLogger error in tomcat 8 eclipse

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am unable to start the Tomcat in Eclipse. Giving me below exception

```
May 31, 2021 2:14:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.66
May 31, 2021 2:14:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 8 2021 22:44:01 UTC
May 31, 2021 2:14:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 8.5.66.0
May 31, 2021 2:14:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10

May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Web]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:827)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Web]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLogger;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
        ... 19 more
    
    May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:827)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OCAWeb]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OCAWeb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLogger;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
        ... 19 more
    
    May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:827)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OCAWeb]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:931)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OCAWeb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LLogger;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
        ... 19 more

May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
May 31, 2021 2:14:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

I have the below log4j jars in my classpath.
log4j-1.2.8.jar
log4j-api-2.10.0.jar

Below ia my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>OCAWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>userLoginBody.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/JSF-Config/third_party_components.xml, /WEB-INF/JSF-Config/navigation.xml, /WEB-INF/JSF-Config/beans.xml, /WEB-INF/JSF-Config/converters.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>tiles-definitions</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100k</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- MyFaces listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>west.ui.bean.SessionLogger</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here. And is it necessary to add these log4j jars in Tomcat server configuration classpath as well?
Note: This is not a Maven build.
Here is my SessionLogger class.

```
package west.ui.bean;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;


import org.apache.log4j.MDC;

import west.ui.bean.locking.LockManager;
import west.ui.bean.navigation.PageNavigator;
import west.ui.bean.user.SessionUserBean;

/**
 * @author Manmeet Vaseer
 * @author Raymond Durkin
 * @author Martin DeLucia
 */
public class SessionLogger implements HttpSessionListener
{
   // private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        
        MDC.put("sessionId", session.getId());
        
        // Used to override the web.xml default settings
        //session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60); //time in seconds
        
        /*if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Session with ID " + session.getId() + " created.");
        }*/
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        try {
            // Unlock any entities that the user might have forgot to unlock in the database.
            SessionUserBean sessionUserBean = (SessionUserBean)event.getSession().getAttribute("sessionUserBean");
            if( sessionUserBean != null ) {
                LockManager lockManager = sessionUserBean.getLockManager();
                if( lockManager != null ) {
                    lockManager.unLockAllEntities();
                }
                
                //Clear the navigation history
                PageNavigator navigator = sessionUserBean.getPageNavigator();
                if( navigator != null ) {
                    navigator.clearHistory();
                }
            }
            
            /*if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Session with ID " + event.getSession().getId() + " destroyed.");
            }*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.warn("Session destroyed problem: " + e.getMessage(), e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging by the stack trace and the lack of package, the missing `Logger` class must be a field in your `west.ui.bean.SessionLogger` listener class. Can you add its source code to the question?

Comment: Yes. I have added in my question description.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse didn't compile the new version of this class (after you commented out `Logger`). Do you have Project > Build automatically enabled? Stop your server, try Project > Clean... and start the server again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.Tried that but no luck. Is there a jar version I need to change?

Comment: I removed west.ui.bean.SessionLogger entry from web.xml. It worked fine.